# Is there a way to set filter values by default in the network tab - Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have few filter values `-.html -.css -.png -.jpg -.jpeg -.ttf -.woff -.svg -.eot -.gif` to filter out the file types from the network tab.

Every time when I'm open the developer tools to filter out these file types, I'm manually adding those negative filters in the filters option.

> [image: Filters]

Is there any way to set these filter values in the network tab filter options by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work on the DevTools team. We do not have this feature. Please star this feature request. More stars = higher priority. https://crbug.com/796893

Comment: Starred the request

Comment: Seems the filters are retained in the browser now, so I accept this answer.